# How do I extract multiple JSON objects from and array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, extract

i've been trying to figure out how to extract multiple JSON objects from a json array.

I used this code from other post

```
$json = '[
            {"user_id":"1",
            "user_name":"Sayeed Amin",
            "time":"2019-11-06 13:21:26"}
        ]';

$someArray = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["user_id"] . ", " . $value["user_name"] . ", " . $value["time"] . "<br>";
}
```

I can use this for a single json object inside an array, the result is good.

RESULT: **1, Sayeed Amin, 2019-11-06 13:21:26**

How about if i have multiple json objects inside and array? like

```
$json = '[
        {"name":"Name",
        "value":"me you",
        "id":0,
        "type":"name",
        "first":"me",
        "middle":"",
        "last":"you"
        },
        {"name":"Email",
        "value":"myemail@gmail.com",
        "id":1,
        "type":"email"
        },
        {"name":"Phone",
        "value":"+12015550000",
        "id":2,"type":"phone"
        },
        {"name":"Address",
        "value":"my address\nsomecity, somestate\nsomepost\nUS",
        "id":3,
        "type":"address",
        "address1":"my address",
        "address2":"",
        "city":"somecity",
        "state":"somestate",
        "postal":"somepost",
        "country":"US"
        }
]';

$someArray = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["name"] . ", " . $value["value"] . "<br>";
}
```

RESULT: **Name, me you 

Email, myemail@gmail.com 

Phone, +12015550000 

Address, my address somecity, somestate somepost US**

DESIRED RESULT: **Name, me you**

Comment: JSON is invalid, `Syntax error, malformed JSON`. You can debug with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php.

Comment: Jason was an Argonaut, JSON is a data transfer standard

Comment: You just need to exit after the first iteration. Could do something like https://3v4l.org/SZcSj. That works because the first `id` is `0`... could also set a variable to 0 before loop and increase by 1 after condition is met.

Comment: The code provided above works, maybe you read before i edited... or maybe you are talking about a part that im missing?

Comment: How do you determine what your desired result is? Is it always the first item in the array, the one with `"id": 0` or the one with `"name": "Name"`? If it's always the first item, just use `$someArray[0]` to get the first object. If you need to check a condition, use an `if` statement inside your loop.

Comment: user3783243 - Maybe i could work with that, but how about if i want the value where id is 1 or 2?

Comment: rickdenhaan - i know it will be in the same position, maybe NAME where ID= 1 or something like that. im very new with php / json

Comment: @Maks You need to use the `@` to tag users. As Rick said you need to use the `if`. Alter from `!empty` to `==`. https://3v4l.org/2m0nM

Comment: @Maks "im very new with php / json" -- that's fine, this is not a programming issue but a logic issue. Think of it this way: if I hand you 4 pieces of paper with name, email, phone and address, in that order, then how would *you* decide which one to keep and which ones to discard? Would you take the first piece of paper or the one that has the name on it? If you want the one with the name, how do you know which one that is? What do you look at to make that determination? Once you figure out what the logic behind it is, having your code do it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to output the First Occurance of the array of objects then address the array appropriately like

```
$json = '[
        {"name":"Name",
        "value":"me you",
        "id":0,
        "type":"name",
        "first":"me",
        "middle":"",
        "last":"you"
        },
        {"name":"Email",
        "value":"myemail@gmail.com",
        "id":1,
        "type":"email"
        },
        {"name":"Phone",
        "value":"+12015550000",
        "id":2,"type":"phone"
        },
        {"name":"Address",
        "value":"my address\nsomecity, somestate\nsomepost\nUS",
        "id":3,
        "type":"address",
        "address1":"my address",
        "address2":"",
        "city":"somecity",
        "state":"somestate",
        "postal":"somepost",
        "country":"US"
        }
]';

$arr = json_decode($json);

echo $arr[0]->name . ", " . $arr[0]->value . "\n";
```

RESULT

```
Name, me you
```