# How do I extract multiple JSON objects from and array with PHP? Part2

Tags: php, arrays, json, extract

This post is in continuation of [How do I extract multiple JSON objects from and array with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64967657/how-do-i-extract-multiple-json-objects-from-and-array-with-php)

Guys, sorry to botter you again, but not sure why, after i changed my form, the values started to be stored like:

```
{"0":{"name":"Name","value":"first last","id":0,"type":"name","first":"first","middle":"","last":"last"},"1":{"name":"Email","value":"someemail@gmail.com","id":1,"type":"email"},"2":{"name":"Phone","value":"+12015550000","id":2,"type":"phone"},"3":{"name":"Address","value":"Address 1\naddress 2\nsomewhere, somewhere\n0000\nUS","id":3,"type":"address","address1":"Address 1","address2":"address 2","city":"somewhere","state":"somewhere","postal":"0000","country":"US"},"19":{"name":"Shop Name","value":"MYSHOP","id":19,"type":"text"}}
```

The **[]** is now **{}**

i would say its nested objects?
in the previous the result was:

```
$arr = json_decode($json);

echo $arr[0]->name . ", " . $arr[0]->value . "\n";
```

im getting damn tired of this json stuff... :(

Can you guys please help me once again?

Thank you in advance

Comment: _“after i changed my form”_ - what form? We never got to see any form in the other question either. Very unclear what you are talking about here, so please clarify what the actual issue is supposed to be here now. And try and make your questions self-contained, so that we can see what your current problem is, without having to refer to other questions in the first place.

Comment: You must have changed something when you create the data, the indexes used to be a number they are now a string.  Have a look at that part (or at least show the code) and that should help.

Comment: You should find the underlying cause to the changes, but for what it's worth, you can reference (get) values inside the json using: `$arr = json_decode($json, true);` this will give you an associative array, which is easy to work with. If you want to get a name, you can then do: `echo $arr[0]['name'];` the first index `[0]` references the first 'record', your provided json's last record index is `[19]`

Comment: @CBroeThe form is from wordpress wpforms, it saves the answers on that form on the database, wich i retrieve the json (thats what looks to me), and im trying to get some specific values from there... 
i've fiddled the form and i couldn't figured it out why it changed from [ ] to { }

Comment: @berend sometimes i feel stupid, and you really made me feel like that.
super simple answer.
i guess thats because im a newb in this json stuff

Comment: That was... not my intention :-) take it easy!

Comment: @berend yeah i know ;) i wasnt complayining about you, i was graceful and tired :P
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Like @berend said.

the answer for what i trying to achieve is:

"You should find the underlying cause to the changes, but for what it's worth, you can reference (get) values inside the json using: $arr = json_decode($json, true); this will give you an associative array, which is easy to work with. If you want to get a name, you can then do: echo $arr[0]['name']; the first index [0] references the first 'record', your provided json's last record index is [19]"